# How to connect MongoDB with Qt c++ ?

Tags: c++, linux, mongodb, qt

I am trying to connect MongoDB with QT c++. I wrote simple application which runs without any error.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    try
    {
        connectMongo();
        qDebug() << "Connection done";
    }
    catch (const mongo::DBException &e)
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed : " << e.what();
    }

}

void MainWindow::connectMongo()
{
        mongo::DBClientConnection c;
        c.connect("127.0.0.1");
}
```

However, when I type "127.0.0.1" or "localhost" it cannot connect and in debug windows it says:

```
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

When I type another value like c.connect("0.0.0.0");

It goes in catch block and exception is :

```
Failed :  can't connect couldn't connect to server 0.0.0.0:27017
```

As far as I understand it works with correct port number, which is describing on MongoDB API as default. So why I cannot use MongoDB and cannot connect it?

Here is output of service;

```
[mg@mg-CentOS ~]$ service mongod status
mongod (pid 4151) is running...
```

Comment: Did you try to wait for the connection to finish? after c.connect("127.0.0.1"). You should also close the connection.

Comment: @Kikohs what you mean about wait? I just give error when I run application and closing.

Comment: You should set a breakpoint to see what's going on. I though that you closed your app instantly. Creating a connection is not instantaneous. So you could create a "delay" function to see if the connection really happens. Also `connect` return a boolean. You should also check it.

Comment: maybe this will help https://github.com/rurounijones/asnme/tree/master

Comment: You have not stated what version of the driver you are using, or what compiler, os, etc. Please see this page for info on the necessary details: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-and-Compile-the-Legacy-Driver#how-to-ask-for-help

Answer (score 1):

[QxOrm library](https://www.qxorm.com/) now supports MongoDB database.
Here is a link to the documentation : https://www.qxorm.com/qxorm_en/manual.html#manual_95